# REST HTTP Accept header mime type for single vs plural

Tags: json, rest, mime-types, http-accept-header

I would like to use the vendor mime type standard in the accept header to handle REST resource requests and versions. We expose a set of get methods for some resources, one returning an array of all or a subset of resources from a search or similar, and the second returning the specific resource if requested by its key value(s).

Array

```
GET .../api/orders?orderDate=2016-01-01
Accept: application/vnd.company.orders.v1+json
```

Single (OrderId = 12345)

```
GET .../api/orders/12345
Accept: application/vnd.company.order.v1+json
```

My question is whether there is a standard around mime types for plural vs. single responses. As shown above, I think that the mime type corresponding to the array response should be plural and single for single. I.e. orders vs. order.

I haven't been able to find anything on this, so any suggestions or links to standards or docs would be great, thanks.

Comment: `vnd` mimetypes are by definition not part of a standard (besides the `vnd` prefix). What you propose looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is the standard [Atom](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023) protocol which somewhat fits the bill. There is also [RSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS). These are not *exactly* only collection types, but they are at least worth considering. (We ended up doing a custom collection format, which was much easier and non-XML)